# ye.auth is not a function @angular/fire

Tags: angular, typescript, firebase, angularfire

I'm using Angular and Firebase to do authentication. It's working perfectly fine locally with no issues. However, when I deploy my application to Netlify and I'm getting an error:

`Uncaught TypeError: ye.auth is not a function`

If I try and login on the built version that same error appears.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is to do with having `optimization: true`. Setting this to false fixes the issue but dramatically increases your bundle size.

https://github.com/angular/angularfire/issues/3221

Answer (score 0):

if anyone is facing this issue in 2023 and the above solution didn't help, this is what helped me:

- First uninstall AngularFire
- Uninstall firebase
- Then install them again exactly in this order:
- npm install @angularfire
- npm install firebase

Somehow, after 6 hours of researching with success,  installing them in this particular order (i.e: AngularFire before installing Firebase) resolved the issue for me.

Cheers!